# ImportError: cannot import name 'dispatcher' for Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I installed scrapy using `pip install scrapy` on Windows 10. It shows `ImportError: cannot import name 'dispatcher'`. I am using Python 3.5.

Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the complete trace:

```
"C:\Users\sameer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
      File "c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 9, in <module>
        from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
      File "c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 15, in <module>
        from scrapy.signalmanager import SignalManager
      File "c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\signalmanager.py", line 2, in <module>
        from pydispatch import dispatcher
    ImportError: cannot import name 'dispatcher'
```

OUTPUT of `pip install scrapy`

```
Requirement already satisfied: scrapy in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cssselect>=0.9 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: parsel>=1.1 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: w3lib>=1.17.0 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (2.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (18.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (4.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: queuelib in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: service-identity in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (17.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Twisted>=13.1.0 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from scrapy) (18.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.2.1 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from service-identity->scrapy) (18.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.4.2 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy) (15.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: incremental>=16.10.1 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy) (17.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.3.0 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy) (18.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy" in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy) (1.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.4.2->Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy) (39.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\sameer\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"->cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy) (2.18)
```

Comment: What's your import lines say?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `pip install dispatcher`

edit:

when trying to install it myself, i've noticed some broken dependencies.

> flask-babelex 0.9.3 requires speaklater>=1.2, which is not installed.
>
> pyasn1-modules 0.2.1 has requirement pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.1, but you'll have pyasn1 0.1.9 which is incompatible.

So I fixed the dependencies as written, first `pip install speaklater`,
then `pip uninstall pyasn1 && pip install pyasn1`

after all dependencies were met, scrapy worked fine.

Can you show the output of 'pip install scrapy'?

Comment: It didn't work even after doing the above thing. As far as output of scrapy is concerned, it says everything was installed perfectly. I will add the output in edit section of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you use `pip` for Python3, in case you also have *Python2* installed. Then you should use: `pip3 install PyDispatcher` (currently at version **2.0.5**). Then you import with:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
...
```

`signal` may or may not be optional, depending on what else you want to do.